# Dictionary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently I tried to reform my JSON data to a dictionary to store only needed data in an array with key and value.

*** Edit to put my full code. ***

This is how I do:

```
var myData = [];
var urlPath = "https://tipjira.pgdev.abcd.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GRIFR14%2Band%2BfixVersion=15018";
var jiraMapping = [];

$.ajax({
    url : "http://frparwself22.dhcp.par.abcd.com:8080/jiraproxy/jira?url=" + urlPath,
    dataType : 'json',
    type: 'GET',

    success : function(data) {
        for (var i=0; i<data.issues.length; i++) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[data.issues[i].key] = data.issues[i].self;
            jiraMapping.push(obj);      
            alert(jiraMapping.length);
        }
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("Error!")
    }
});

alert(jiraMapping.length);
```

My original data is {issues:[{...,"self":"/rest/api/2/issue/175074","key":"GRIFR14-36",...}, {...,"self":"/rest/api/2/issue/175075","key":"GRIFR14-37",...}, ...]}. And I want to reform to have the array with key and value which are key and self.

So the data in my jiraMapping should be something like `[{k1:v1}, {k2,v2}, ...]`.
But when I tired to print the length of jiraMapping, the length is 0.
I tried to put alert to check key and value that I add to the array and the values exist.

I don't know where is the problem exactly. Please help...

Comment: Could you provide the format of your input data? Is it {issues:[{key: _keyvalue_, self: _selfValue_}]} ?

Comment: So, jiraMapping DOES have [{k1:v1}, {k2,v2}, ...], then? That's an array of objects and length should work.

Comment: Is it ajax ? Are you retrieving JSON ? Where do you need to catch the `jiraMapping` again ?

Comment: You didn't forget to parse the JSON, did you?

Comment: The data it's something like this [{GBC0001, http://link1.com}, {GBC0001, http://link2.com},....]. I need to use this array to render in the UI later. So it's easier to manage the data.

Comment: My original data is {issues:[{...,"self":"/rest/api/2/issue/175074","key":"GRIFR14-36",...}, {...,"self":"/rest/api/2/issue/175075","key":"GRIFR14-37",...}, ...]}. And I want to reform to have the array with key and value which are key and self.

Comment: The problem is solved... I put async:false.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what information you're passing in, it's hard to say what's going wrong. That being said, my first guess is that `data`/`myData` isn't formatted the way you think. For instance, if `myData.issues.length` is `0`, nothing in the loop will get executed.

There's also a chance that you're never actually running the `success` function. Could you post some more code?

Comment: I tried to print the length inside the for loop and the length of jiraMapping is increased. But outside the ajax code, jiraMapping.lenght = 0.

Comment: What's the scope of jiraMapping? Could it be defined elsewhere? Is it modified anywhere else?

Comment: No, it's not modified anywhere else. I read the data from URL and after that I just reform the original data to jiraMapping. This is example of my original data... {issues:[{...,"self":"/rest/api/2/issue/175074","key":"GRIFR14-36",...}, {...,"self":"/rest/api/2/issue/175075","key":"GRIFR14-37",...}, ...]}

Comment: As Juzer Ali asked earlier, do you use `JSON.parse()` on your data after retrieving it via ajax?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the data that you are receiving or you have a typo somewhere later when checking length. This all looks fine, and I tried to replicate your problem like this:

```
var jiraMapping = [];    
var myData = [{"A":"a"},{"B":"b"}];
for (var i=0; i<myData.length; i++) {
var obj = {};
obj[myData[i]] = myData[i];
jiraMapping.push(obj);    
}
console.log(jiraMapping);
```

but this works fine, fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GWpBs/2/

Comment: I check your code. The length of jiraMapping is 2 indeed, but it contains ['undefined': 'undefined','undefined': 'undefined']. As far as I'm aware, object.key and object.self don't exist...

Comment: As I already inform above, I alert the value of key and self to check and the values exist.

Comment: Still need updating: this will give jiraMapping=[{"a":"a", "b":"b"}]; In any case, if myData had this format, jiraMapping = myData would be what you want to do.

Comment: The problem is solved... I put async:false.

Thanks you guys!